# How to add a String Set in DynamoDB using Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-dynamodb

I want to add to a String Set (String Set) in DynamoDB, using Ruby.

(This also applies to Number Sets or Binary Sets)

- Searching the [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/DynamoDB.html) doesn’t return anything for StringSet or String Set
- Looking at other resources on the web, such as [from ReadySteadyCode](https://readysteadycode.com/howto-access-amazon-dynamodb-with-ruby) aren’t clear how you create a set as it just says `Set` without any reference to where that comes from.
- In other languages such as JavaScript, you use `dynamoClient.createSet([value])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `Set` is all you need if you have included the AWS SDK, although it’s hard to find a reference to it.

Something like this will work:

```
update_expression: 'ADD #attribute :value',
expression_attribute_names: {
  '#attribute' => attribute
},
expression_attribute_values: {
  ':value' => Set.new([value])
},
```